# Java update global variable between classes

Tags: java, global-variables

I have a public static string called randomWord. After a different class runs a method I want the "value" of it to change. An example: Class Variables having the public static String randomWord; Class 1 does some stuff and sets Variables.randomWord = orange. Class 2 needs to get the new randomWord. What's a possible method for updating the randomWord in class variable?

Thanks in advance

```
    public final class Variables
{
    public static String randomWord;
}
```

Class ^

```
    public static String pickWord()
        throws IOException
{    
    File words = new File("wordList.txt");
    String wordToArray;
    String[] arrWord = new String[3863];   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(words);
    Random rWord = new Random();
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        sc.nextLine();
        wordToArray = sc.next();
        arrWord[i] = wordToArray;
        i++;    
    }while(sc.hasNext());

    Arrays.toString(arrWord);
    int idx = rWord.nextInt(arrWord.length);

    Variables.randomWord = (arrWord[idx]);
    System.out.println(Variables.randomWord);
    return Variables.randomWord;
}
```

Where I change the value, set the .txt document of words into the array, and randomly get a word from the array. Class 1

```
String selectedWord = Variables.randomWord;
            System.out.println("Got your word, get ready!" + selectedWord);
            return selectedWord;
```

where I need the new value Class 2

Answer (score 0):

You can do just that. Create a class, add the public static variable and modify the variable Variables.randomWord. But it would be wiser to make this class final, make the static var private and use static functions to get and set this variable (encapsulation)

Comment: I know I _can_ but how? How do I tell the class to update the variable?

Comment: By having the class call a static function you created called Variables.setRandomWord(). Because it is static, you do not need to instantiate new Variables(). It is available anywhere.

Comment: But in Variables.setRandomWord() how would I get the updated value?

Comment: By also adding a static Function like getRandomWord() returning the string

Comment: ... I have the slight feeling you're taunting me xD We are going in a circle. I am asking what code I would do to update the variable. How would I tell this variable it needs to be updated. new Variables.randomWord = Class.settingRandomWord();

Comment: Public final class Variables(){ public static randomword}

Comment: Say you were trying to do this, what would you? Because all this has told me is that your way of doing it would be make a method in the Variables class. That's it.

Comment: Then your class1 : assuming you created a myclass= new Class1(); You have the following in either the constructor or in another function, call Variables.randomWord= aclass.getRandomWords().

Comment: Now be sure you created a function getRandomWords()    somewhere to get a randomword from say an arraylist filled with strings where you pick one using Math.random.getnextint().

Comment: I already have the random word. I already have all the possible words. I just need to set a public variable to be updated to the randomly selected word.

Comment: Okay I lost you completely. Looking at your updated code, it looks like you already know what to do.

Comment: I print the value out to see if it is working correctly, if it prints null it does not work. So what is happening is I am not getting the new value that Class1 updated and I don't know how to or why,

Comment: Where did you declare Function pickword()? In Variables? If so did you call Variables.pickword() before you tried to get it and print it? If so, could you call pickword right before you print it?

Comment: pickWord() is in Class 1

Comment: Well again looking at your updated code you should at least see a print of the word in pickWord. If you don't, then I would suggest you debug this pickWord function to see if the file is actually adding words to your array.

Answer (score 0):

A working example (given that you have the file wordList.txt path set properly)

Variables.java:
    package com.avk.randomword;

```
public final class Variables {

    private static String randomWord;

    public static String getRandomWord(){
        return randomWord;
    }

    public static void setRandomWord( String randomWord ){
        Variables.randomWord = randomWord; 
    }
}
```

Class1.java:

```
package com.avk.randomword;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class1 {

    public String pickWord(){    
        String              wordToArray;
        String              randomWord;
        ArrayList<String>   arrWord         = new ArrayList<String>();
        Random              rWord           = new Random();

        try{
            File words          = new File("wordList.txt");
            Scanner sc          = new Scanner(words);

            while( sc.hasNext() ) {
                wordToArray = sc.next().trim();
                if( wordToArray.length() > 0 ){
                    arrWord.add( wordToArray );
                }
            }

        }catch( IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if( arrWord.size() <= 0 ){
            System.out.println( "No words found in array arrWord" );
            return null;
        }
        int idx = rWord.nextInt( arrWord.size() -1 );

        randomWord = arrWord.get(idx);

        Variables.setRandomWord( randomWord );
        System.out.println( "Class1 set Variables.randomWord to: "  + Variables.getRandomWord());
        return Variables.getRandomWord();
    }   

}
```

Class2:

```
package com.avk.randomword;

public class Class2 {

    // Constructor
    public Class2(){
        System.out.println( "This is Class2 getting the randomWord from final class Variables: " + Variables.getRandomWord() );
    }

}
```

Main.java:

```
package com.avk.randomword;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 myClass1 = new Class1();
        myClass1.pickWord();

        Class2 myClass2 = new Class2();

    }

}
```

If the wordList.txt looks like this:

```
apple
pear

orange
banana
```

A possible correct output would be:

```
Class1 set Variables.randomWord to: pear
This is Class2 getting the randomWord from final class Variables: pear
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not seem to be quite what I am looking for, It's fine. I will just figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

Needs to be added in class 1

```
Variables.randomWord = Variables.randomWord = (arrWord[idx]);
```